# how to replace pattern from dataframe's specific column and that specific column passing from another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, gsub

I have two data frames as below

```
DF1 ->
    name  age  data  exp  flush
    Rohan 23   124.0 2.0  38.0
    Rajan 25   230.0 2.0  38.0
    Dom   32   321.0 6.0  38.0
```

i want to replace ".0" from above dataframe's specific column given in another dataframe as below

```
DF2->
    columnName
    data
    flush
```

sample output i want is as below

```
name  age  data  exp  flush
Rohan 23   124   2.0  38
Rajan 25   230   2.0  38
Dom   32   321   6.0  38
```

i tried below part but and it is working if i pass column using $ and its returning value but i want complete dataframe as shown in output with columns passing from another dataframe.

```
im <- gsub(".0+$", "", DF1$data ))
```

Comment: Try `new <- type.convert(DF1);new`.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `across`, `case_when` and `str_replace_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DF1 %>% 
mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(cur_column() %in% DF2$columnName ~ str_replace_all(.,".0", ""),
                                       TRUE ~ as.character(.))
              )
       )
```

data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(name = c("Rohan","Rajan","Dom"),
                  age = c(23,25,32),
                  data = c("124.0","230.0","321.0"),
                  exp = c("2.0","2.0","2.0"),
                  flush = c("38.0","38.0","38.0"))

DF2 <- data.frame(columnName = c("data", "flush"))
```

Output:

```
   name age data exp flush
1 Rohan  23  124 2.0    38
2 Rajan  25    2 2.0    38
3   Dom  32  321 2.0    38
```